# Error on Retrieving saved listitems from Preference on onCreate in Android

Tags: android, listview, sharedpreferences

I have a list Adapter. I am trying to save list items in preference and call back on onCreate during Restart of phone so that i do not loose any of my list items. Now during onCreate i am checking if adapter is empty or not. This works fine but recalling values from Preferences giving below error. Can anyone guess what is error about ? Below is error and code :

Editing question and adding committing part class code. You can find committing between comments "/*Log Success Push Report*/"

Error :

```
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.teleca.sam.engine/com.teleca.sam.ui.LogListView}: java.util.NoSuchElementException
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1941)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:705)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:369)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:150)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:560)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4223)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17275)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264): Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:208)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at com.teleca.sam.ui.LogListView.onCreate(LogListView.java:71)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
11-18 12:42:25.740: E/AndroidRuntime(7264):     ... 18 more
11-18 12:42:25.770: E/android.os.Debug(2281): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Code :

```
public class LogListView extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static String newString;
    private static EntryAdapter adapter;
    int clickCounter = 0;
    static ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    static SharedPreferences preferences = null;
    private static Context context = null;
    static StringTokenizer tokens;
    private static String first;
    private static String second;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = this;
        adapter = new EntryAdapter(this, items);
        //items.add(new SectionItem("Log Report"));
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        if(adapter.getCount()!=0){
            //Do nothing Adapter has value 
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(LogListView.this, "No Items Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            addItems();
        }

    }

    // Method which will handle dynamic insertion
    public static void addItems() {

        preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("LOG",
                android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        newString = preferences.getString("log", "");

        tokens = new StringTokenizer(newString, ",");
        first = tokens.nextToken();
        second = tokens.nextToken();

        items.add(new EntryItem(first, second));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    // Method which will handle dynamic insertion ends

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        if (!items.get(position).isSection()) {

            EntryItem item = (EntryItem) items.get(position);
            // Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + item.title ,
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }

        if (position == 9) {

        }

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }
```

Class where commit is done

```
public class Support extends TabActivity {

    // private ImageView mSpinnerImage = null;
    // private Animation mAnimation = null;
    private Button syncbutton = null;
    private TextView synctitle = null;
    private Button home = null;
    private Button messages = null;
    private Button history = null;
    private Button settings = null;
    private Button support = null;
    private TabHost mTabHost = null;

    private Preferences prefs = Preferences.getInstance();
    private Context context = null;
    private SharedPreferences eulapreferences = null;
    private boolean vpnenableboolean = false;
    private Editor defaultprefsedit = null;
    private int acrTransmissionRate = 0;
    private long shortsleeptime = 0;
    private static final String PREFERENCE_EULA_ACCEPTED = "eula.accepted";
    private static final String PREFERENCES_EULA = "eula";
    private SharedPreferences defaultprefs = null;
    private int vpnenable;
    public static int data_reset = 0;
    private String appVersion;
    private static int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    private String strName;
    private SimpleDateFormat s;
    private String format;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* Titlebar + Button */
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.support);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.window_title);
        syncbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.syncbutton);


        /*Reset Service Parameters*/
        context = this;
        prefs = Preferences.getInstance();
        eulapreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_EULA, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        defaultprefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        defaultprefsedit = defaultprefs.edit();

        shortsleeptime = prefs.getShortSleepTime(context);
        acrTransmissionRate = prefs.getAcrUploadTime(context);
        vpnenable = (prefs.getVpnenable(context));              
        vpnenableboolean  = (vpnenable != 0);
        /*Reset Service Parameters ends*/


        syncbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /*Reset Service*/
                if (DataTransLayer.canTransferData(context)){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Reset Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                data_reset = 1;
                Intent svc = new Intent(context, EngineService.class);
                svc.setAction(EngineLauncher.ACTION_ALARM);
                context.startService(svc);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context,AppInventoryService.class);
                intent.setAction(AppInventoryService.ACTION_METER_MANAGER_PUSH);
                context.startService(intent);
                if (eulapreferences.getBoolean(PREFERENCE_EULA_ACCEPTED, false) && Preferences.getInstance().getRegistrationStatus(context)) {
                    schedulealarmservice(context);
                    scheduleacruploadalarmservice(context, true);

                }

                /*Log Success Push Report*/
                format = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                strName = "Sync Successful" + "," + format;

                SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("LOG", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("log", strName);
                editor.commit();

                Log.d("LOG", "Sent : " + strName);

                LogListView.addItems();
                /*Log Success Push Report*/


                if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH && !prefs.getTunInterfaceNotAvilableStatus(context)) {
                    if (vpnenableboolean && !prefs.getTunInterfaceNotAvilableStatus(context)) {
                        String prefix = OpenVPNService.INTENT_PREFIX;
                        Intent stopintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                OpenVPNService.class).setAction(
                                OpenVPNService.ACTION_DISCONNECT).putExtra(
                                prefix + ".STOP", true);
                        startService(stopintent);
                        defaultprefsedit.putString("currentstate", "DISCONNECTED");
                        defaultprefsedit.commit();
                        OpenVPNService.current_state = "DISCONNECTED";
                        prefs.setOpenVpnConfigStatus(context, true);
                        prefs.setVpnPopupCancelStatus(context, false);
                        Intent ovpnintent = new Intent(context,
                                OpenVpnHelperService.class);
                        ovpnintent
                                .setAction(OpenVpnServiceLauncher.ACTION_OPEN_VPN_METER_PUSH);
                        context.startService(ovpnintent);
                    }

                }

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check network connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                    /*Log Failed Push Report*/
                    format = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    strName = "Sync Failed" + "," + format;

                    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("LOG", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("log", strName);
                    editor.commit();

                    Log.d("LOG", "Failed : " + strName);

                    LogListView.addItems();
                    /*Log Failed Push Report*/

                }
                /*Reset Service ends*/


            }
        });
        /* Titlebar + Button ends */

        /* Bottom Buttons */
        home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
        messages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.messages);
        history = (Button) findViewById(R.id.history);
        settings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings);
        support = (Button) findViewById(R.id.support);
        home.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        messages.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        history.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        settings.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        support.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        /* Bottom Buttons ends */


        /*OnClick Home Button*/
        home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Support.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                Support.this.startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
        /*OnClick Home Button ends*/

        /* Tabs */
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        // First Activity
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, InfoListView.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("some_things").setIndicator("Info").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Second Activity
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, LogListView.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("top_things").setIndicator("Log").setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).getLayoutParams().height = 95;
        //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).getLayoutParams().height = 95;
        /* Tabs ends */
    }

    /*Reset Service*/
    private void schedulealarmservice(Context appcontext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d("schedulealarmservice", "schedulealarmservice");
        AlarmManager acrservice = (AlarmManager) appcontext
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(appcontext, AlarmServiceReceiver.class);
        i.setAction(AcrServiceLauncher.ACTION_ACR_ALARM_INTENT);
        PendingIntent acrpending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appcontext, 0, i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, (int) shortsleeptime);

        acrservice.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                acrpending);

    }

    private void scheduleacruploadalarmservice(Context appcontext,Boolean flag) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("schedulealarmservice", "scheduleacruploadalarmservice");
        AlarmManager uploadservice = (AlarmManager) appcontext
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(appcontext, AlarmServiceReceiver.class);
        i.setAction(AcrServiceLauncher.ACTION_ACR_UPLOAD_INTENT);
        PendingIntent uploadintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appcontext, 0,
                i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        if(flag){
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        }else{
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, acrTransmissionRate * 60);
        }

        uploadservice.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                uploadintent);

    }
    /*Reset Service Ends*/

}
```

Comment: You have to commit the SharedPreference object

Comment: @Andrain : Line 77 is "newString = preferences.getString("log", "");"

Comment: @RahulGupta : Committing is already done in another class. Here retrieval part is carried out.

Comment: Post your code with committing part.

Comment: @Andrain : Added committing part class code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put this code at your addItems() Method.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("LOG", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = preferences.edit(); // you have to open shared preference in Edit mode
newString = preferences.getString("log", "");
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I am anyway editing while saving. While retrieving i never heard of using editor. Even if i use the line "SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();" you suggested it will remain unused.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is probably because `newString` is empty (nothing found in SharedPreferences) so when you call `tokens.nextToken()`, there is nothing there, hence the error "no such element". Are you sure you are saving the preferences before leaving the activity? Your `commit()` seems to be called from a click listener which might not always be triggered.

In any case, you need to handle the cases where `newString` is indeed supposed to be empty. Add a check before starting the tokenizer to make sure.

Comment: I have rewrite question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043277/listview-emptying-on-restart-of-phone-how-to-save-state-of-listitems